Dockerised Django project not serving files after trying to adjust static configuration
I'm running a dockerised web application using Django. I have had issues with getting static files to work (I couldn't get the application to find them), I thought I had this figured out that the files had the wrong permissions and added my current usergroup to it. After this the application won't run.
What do I mean by won't run?
I now get OOM messages from Gunicorn which I never got until I changed permissions on the root static folder. It's not a very intense application so far which makes me doubt it's a memory issue.
[2024-08-30 19:08:12 +0000] [1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 23.0.0
[2024-08-30 19:08:12 +0000] [1] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8000 (1)
[2024-08-30 19:08:12 +0000] [1] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2024-08-30 19:08:12 +0000] [7] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 7
[2024-08-30 19:08:52 +0000] [1] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:7)
[2024-08-30 19:08:53 +0000] [1] [ERROR] Worker (pid:7) was sent SIGKILL! Perhaps out of memory?
[2024-08-30 19:08:53 +0000] [8] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 8

My feeling is that changing permissions has caused some issues. This is the current permission setup:
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ash ash  757 Aug 30 20:17 docker-compose.yml
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ash ash  965 Aug 26 18:02 Dockerfile
drwxrwxr-x 7 ash ash 4096 Aug 26 18:32 gs-python
drwxr-xr-x 3 ash ash 4096 Aug 16 20:12 nginx
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ash ash    6 Aug 15 17:16 README.md
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ash ash   31 Aug 15 19:06 requirements.txt
drwxrwxrwx 2 ash ash 4096 Aug 30 19:50 static

docker-compose.yml
version: '3.8'

services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: gunicorn app-name.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - ./gs-python:/app
      - ./gs-python/static:/app/static  # Directly mount local static folder
    expose:
      - "8000"
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    image: postgres:13
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: 
      POSTGRES_USER: 
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 

  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    volumes:
      - ./static:/app/static  
      - ./nginx/conf.d/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    ports:
      - "8001:80"
    depends_on:
      - web

volumes:
  postgres_data:

Dockerfile
# Step 1: Use an official Python runtime as a parent image
FROM python:3.9-slim

# Step 2: Set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

# Step 3: Set up working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Step 4: Install system dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    python3-dev \
    libpq-dev \
    postgresql-client \
    build-essential \
    nginx \
    curl \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Step 5: Install Python dependencies
COPY requirements.txt /app/
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# Step 6: Copy project files
COPY . /app/

# Step 7: Set up database 
# RUN python manage.py makemigrations
# RUN python manage.py migrate

# Step 8: Collect static files
RUN python gs-python/manage.py collectstatic --noinput

# Step 9: Gunicorn command to run the app
CMD ["gunicorn", "--bind", "0.0.0.0:8000", "app-name.wsgi:application"]

nginx default.conf
server {
    listen 80;
    
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://web:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    location /static/ {
        alias /app/static/; 
        autoindex on;
    }
}

I added an image of the Dir structure. I have 2 static folders, I'm not sure when this generation happened, likely during my attempts to configure it.


Managed to solve this. For I checked the Gunicorn container and for some reason I had it loading the entire project dir via this line:
volumes:
- ./gs-python:/app

Removing this and applying some migrations seemed to have fixed my issue.
